# Difference between Services and Services.Client layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an MVC4 existing application. The application is related to web services.

There are 4 projects in the application:

1. **DataLayer** - Contains edmx files
2. **Web** - Contains:

   Models, Views and Controllers

   Service References naming ProfileService and EditorService
3. **Services** - Contains:

   Data Models (sending/receiving of data with database)

   IProfileService and IEditorService

   ProfileService.svc and EditorService.svc
4. **Services.Client** - Contains ProfileService.cs and EditorService.cs

---

**My Questions:**

1. Can someone help me understand the relationship between these
   projects?
2. In Service.Client, ProfileService.cs and EditorService.cs are
   auto-generated files. Can I know how these class files are created?
3. What is the difference between Services and Services.Client?

Below is the upload of ProfileService.cs file (auto generated)

[image]

Comment: What does auto-generated files in Services.Client look like?

Comment: @ken2k, have a look.
i have uploaded the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Relationships (as in a typical architecture): Web accesses services, Services accesses DataLayer. Services.Client might be a library for projects that want to access the Services directly - and as such could also be used by the Web application.
2. Typically, these files are created when adding a service reference to a project. You can also use [svcutil.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347733%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to generate them. If there are no service references in the project, the probability is high that the latter approach was used.
3. Services are installed on a server and offer the services to clients. Service.Client provides the infrastructure to access the services. These are used by a client to the server. Note that in this case the term "client" refers to any software accessing the services and does not mean that it has to run on a client computer. The web application that is hosted on the server is also a client of the services.

Comment: @Marcus, it works.
I explored more about svcutil, it created the class file.

Comment: @Marcus, another question that arises is:
If I create a method or add a column(with database) in svc file, do I have to recreate class again and again using svcutil.exe ?

Comment: @vipul.surana: yes you do have to recreate the classes again if the contract of your service changes. Therefore it pays off if you do not change the contract too often. However, you might not need to recreate the classes if your changes are not breaking, e.g. if you added a new method or you added a field that is not required - but as soon as you need the method or field, you'd have to recreate the file of course. For details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733832(v=vs.110).aspx